# How can I hide the navigation buttons and the pagination in SlidesJS?

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, slideshow

I downloaded [SlideJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) and I'm trying to hide the navigation buttons and the pagination to get a sipmle automatic slideshow but I can't figure it out.
How can it be done?

Comment: Why negative to the question? It is a valid question. I hate people who just love to click the down arrow without any valid reason :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code. You just need to activate few options as you can see below.

Here is the demo: http://jsbin.com/AtiWOVAD/1/edit

```
$(function () {
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    play: {
        active: false,
        effect: "slide",
        interval: 2000,
        auto: true,
        swap: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        restartDelay: 2000
    },
    navigation: false
  });
});
```